# Android - Populate section on actiontab with strings.xml

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager

I am been trying to get section headings for my tabs on my view pager from the strings.xml but up to now i can't get it to work. It was working fine if I combined my MainActivity class with my SectionPagerAdapter. However i decided to separate them because i find it neat for someone to read my code though i can't find a solution to retrieve the strings in strings.xml

I have initialize a MainActivity in my adapter class

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

and i have point them to find for the strings.xml through this way where i populate the headers.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
{
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return main.getString(R.string.title_section1);
        case 1:
            return main.getString(R.string.title_section2);
        case 2:
            return main.getString(R.string.title_section3);
        case 3:
            return main.getString(R.string.title_section4);
    }
    return "failed";
}
```

however it is giving me nullpointerexception whenever this runs and the app force close straight away. Is there a way to actually point my adapter class to the strings.xml since the adapter class is not extending on activity?

Comment: Never ever create a new Activity like that. If you only need the activity for `getString` then use a `Context` for that.

Comment: Could you give an example code? I did give it a try but it doesnt seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the Context via the constructor (or via a setter). Your class should look like this:

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private Context context = null;

    public SectionPagerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return context.getString(R.string.title_section1);
            case 1:
                return context.getString(R.string.title_section2);
            case 2:
                return context.getString(R.string.title_section3);
            case 3:
                return context.getString(R.string.title_section4);
        }
        return "failed";
    }

    ...
}
```